# Azure Logic Apps interferes with SQL Server operations - causes time-outs in node-red which inserts messages from IoT device into SQL DB

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-sql-server

I have a database in Azure SQL Server, which stores messages from IoT devices. Those devices send periodic messages to a listener which is set up (along with a lot of logic before it ends up in SQL DB) and runs in node-red. Everything works well for a couple of weeks now.

Enter Logic Apps. I have a simple trigger that executes two stored procedures on a schedule (one issues major update on one table that is also used in trigger (on a table in SQL) firing when node-red inserts data, second inserts data into a table feeding PowerBI dashboard. Total runtime for two executions is less than 20 seconds.

The moment this trigger is enabled, node-red starts experiencing time-outs when connecting to the server. And I am literal: for 3 days no issues, enabled Logic Apps trigger and I can see incomplete data saved in DB. It doesn't even have to run, just enabled causes issues.

It was disabled last week due to same issues, though we didn't know then this was the cause. We assumed neighbors were crowding us and tier was low on that db. But we forked out some cash and upgraded. Yet problem is back. And I can definitely state this is the ONLY change that was made on Azure in regards to that setup in 3 days.

I am kinda stumped - not sure what is happening, so not sure how to fix it except disabling trigger again. What is going on?

Comment: You can refer to [Handle stored procedure timeouts in the SQL connector for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-long-running-stored-procedures-sql-connector) and [Messages and Topics from IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/528727/messages-and-topics-from-iot-hub.html)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT it's not the problem in stored procedure timeouts, it's in the connector from mqtt broker in node-red to SQL. It's like Logic App imposes severe penalty on SQL Server performance just by running on subscription or it interferes in SQL operations to such level that 20% of messages from IoT device goes missing. I can see that difference between two DBs - one of which Logic App is configured on and the other one without. Thank you for the links, though - some interesting reading I found there.

Comment: This looks like a locks. What exactly your store proc doing? is it modifying the same table where node-red writing?

Comment: @FreemanRU Sort of. Stored proc is updating tables which are populated by TRIGGER that is created on a table that node-red is writing to.

Comment: @FreemanRU The problem is that ALA triggers every 2 hours and node-red writes to two tables in SQL Server every 30 min. Only one of those two tables has SQL Trigger created, but node-red reports timeouts on both tables. I am literal when stating that just enabling ALA trigger causes timeouts.

Comment: Just take the statistic about locks on the database when timeout occurs. At least you will have some info.